# ASP.NET WEBAPI referenced types are not automatically binded

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have these 2 simple classes:

```
public class Customer
{
    public virtual int Id{get;set;}
    public virtual string Name{get;set;}
    public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
}

public class Brand
{
    public virtual int Id{get;set;}        
}
```

In my webapi when I 'POST' or 'PUT' `Customer` to:

```
public void Post([FromBody]Customer entity)
```

it does not create the `Brand` reference.

this is the Customer submitted data:

```
Name: "Some Customer Name"
Brand.Id: "2"  // <<---- this suppose to instanciate Brand inside Customer with "3" as Id
```

instead I am getting null.
I am almost sure that MVC Brand model would have been binded.

**Update1**
This is how the data is sent:
[image]

Comment: This seems to be begging the question. Are you sure that the data that's submitted is in fact the right format for Web API to recognize? Can you show code that does the POST request and what the request body actually is?

Comment: @millimoose I have updated the question, see UPDATE1

Comment: This question has very little to do with Web API and a whole lot to do with JSON.NET.  JSON.NET is the default json serializer in Web API, if you understand how JSON.NET serialization works you will have the answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you submit JSON data. In this case, try to change the data you send to:

```
{
    Name: "Some Customer Name", 
    Brand: { Id: "2" }
}
```

As Brand is a sub-object, you specify its values in a separate block of curly braces.